# Chrome extension unload every time when reopen chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created one simple chrome extension.
But every time I restart/reopen chrome browser it gets automatically unloaded. I need to load it every time when I open chrome browser.

I feel like this is not the issue with the code.

Please see following steps.

> 1. I loaded extension as unpack extension in chrome.
> 2. As I currently loaded it work perfectly as expected.
> 3. Now I closed chrome browser.
> 4. reopen browser  Now i need to load extension as unpack extension.

What would be the case for that?
Any suggestions will be helpfull.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "unloaded". Please elaborate, maybe add a screenshot.

Comment: Unload means it removed from extensions as it is loaded as unpack extension.

Comment: Without more details, this sounds like a bug in the browser.

Comment: This is my client's words I have asked for video what is happening let's see what comes from their end.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Standard Chrome disables unpacked extensions in Windows automatically. Your client will have to switch to a non-Google fork like CentBrowser, or use Chrome Canary or Chrome dev channel.